# ARM Cortex-M3 PC loaded with invalid address?

Tags: arm, disassembly

On a device with 128kB flash (0x0-0x0001FFFF) and 20kB SRAM (0x20000000-0x20004FFF), why would the PC (program counter) be set to an address in the range 0x1001xxxx?

- Am I looking at incorrect disassembly?
- Are there "special" bits used by the ARM core?
- Is that an access to a flash region that I have not yet found the documentation for?
- ...?

Comment: what specific chip is this, cant help without that.  look at the chip docs the application flash and/or bootloader flash is likely mirrored there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything below `0x20000000` is valid code address space for Cortex-M. This could be implemented as ROM, flash, or remapped RAM - it's entirely device specific.

If it's immediately after boot, some type of ROM wouldn't be unsurprising, but a better answer will need more details of device and exactly when this occurs ...